# pandas dataframe by user input

Tags: python, pandas, input

I have a question about importing a dataframe by user input. I want to create a pandas dataframe by user input. The first line contains the number of rows in the data. The second line contains comma separated headers of the data frame. The third and subsequent line contains the dataframe data.

For example I have 
line 1: 3
line 2: variable 1, variable 2, variable 3 
line 3: 3, 4, 8
line 4: 5, 6, 9
line 5: 1, 7, 4

can you please help me with an input function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
In [48]: total_rows = int(input("Enter number of data rows:"))                                                                                                                                              
Enter number of data rows:3

In [50]: header = input("Enter header:")                                                                                                                                                                    
Enter header:variable 1, variable 2, variable 3

In [51]: data = [] 

In [63]: i = 1                                                                                                                                                                                              

In [64]: while i <= total_rows: 
    ...:     row = input("Enter data:") 
    ...:     data.append(row) 
    ...:     i += 1 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Enter data:3, 4, 8
Enter data:5, 6, 9
Enter data:1, 7, 4

In [66]: header = header.split(',')
In [74]: data = [x.split(',') for x in data]                                                                                                                                                                

In [75]: df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)                                                                                                                                                            

In [76]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[76]: 
  variable 1  variable 2  variable 3
0          3           4           8
1          5           6           9
2          1           7           4
```